# Google apps script :: Is it possible to get the cursor position or get the selected text from Google Document

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is there any Google Apps Script API to get the cursor position or get the selected text from Google Document. I have searched for this and found nothing. If anyone knew about this case please help me.

Thanks,
Vinod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no such API. However, there is an [open issue on the Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2865). You can star this issue to register your interest and be notified to update to it

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method [Highlight and then select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16641880/1993938).   It is definitely a work around, but it may suit your needs. A weakness of this method is that it will select all of the highlighted text of the specified color.

```
function findHighlighted() {
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody(),
      bodyTextElement = body.editAsText(),
      bodyString = bodyTextElement.getText(),
      char, len;

  for (char = 0, len = bodyString.length; char < len; char++) {
    if (bodyTextElement.getBackgroundColor(char) == '#ffff00') // Yellow
      Logger.log(bodyString.charAt(char))}
}
```

The previous answer is technically correct, in that a direct method for selecting text with mouse/cursor is not yet included in the API.

Comment: I have checked this type of getting the selected text based on background color.But what I need is mouse selected text. Thanks for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Add-ons quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs) has a sample with the following method:

```
/**
 * Gets the text the user has selected. If there is no selection,
 * this function displays an error message.
 *
 * @return {Array.<string>} The selected text.
 */
function getSelectedText() {
  var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
  if (selection) {
    var text = [];
    var elements = selection.getSelectedElements();
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if (elements[i].isPartial()) {
        var element = elements[i].getElement().asText();
        var startIndex = elements[i].getStartOffset();
        var endIndex = elements[i].getEndOffsetInclusive();

        text.push(element.getText().substring(startIndex, endIndex + 1));
      } else {
        var element = elements[i].getElement();
        // Only translate elements that can be edited as text; skip images and
        // other non-text elements.
        if (element.editAsText) {
          var elementText = element.asText().getText();
          // This check is necessary to exclude images, which return a blank
          // text element.
          if (elementText != '') {
            text.push(elementText);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (text.length == 0) {
      throw 'Please select some text.';
    }
    return text;
  } else {
    throw 'Please select some text.';
  }
}
```